# Monero CLI wallet, change restore height

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, wallet-recovery, block-height

Situation: I am using the monero-wallet-cli and I have a wallet file and a keys already.
The point is that when I was initially restoring that wallet, I gave a restore height, for instance 2600000.

Question: Now that I want to change that height in CLI wallet, how can I do it?

I know there is an easy fix on the GUI wallet, right? But where is this option on the CLI wallet? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[wallet xyz]: help set
Command usage: 
  set <option> [<value>]

Command description: 
  Available options:
   ...
   refresh-from-block-height [n]
     Set the height before which to ignore blocks.
   ...
```

Comment: so let's say i am connecting to my wallet file and after entering the wallet password, i am in. Then it starts refreshing. 
So, at this point, i should ctrl+c to stop it, right? 
It will prompt me with out of sync, then i run "set refresn-from-block-height"?

Another thing i found strange is that when i was restoring a wallet from seed with a height 2600000, it actually did refresh from the very beginning.. it didn't start refreshing from the given 2600000 height. Why is that? 


Thank you!!!

Comment: Ctrl-C will interrupt your current refresh. Ensure you spell correctly, type + hit enter: `set refresh-from-block-height 2600000`. Then type + enter: `refresh`.

Comment: thank you sir. i will definitely try it when i go back home.
Meanwhile can you also help answer:

why it refreshed from block 1  when i was firstly restore from seed, setting height to 2600000. Thanks.

Comment: "can you also help answer..." are you using the latest version? are you sure you entered correctly?